# how to calculate commission using stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, crystal-reports

I am having a table contains PrincipalAmount field. I need to calculate commission on the base of PrincipalAmount 
i.e. if PrincipalAmount < 25000.99 Commission = 125
            //         // 50000.99  //       // 250

Can someone please write a stored procedure so i can display all data in crystal report.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: or is it possible to create this formula in crystal report?

Comment: StackOverflow is here to help you when you have problems in your code. Not as a free development base. If you attempt to write this yourself we can help point out areas you can improve, or tell you where you are going wrong. We can even point you in the right directions for learning materials if you have no experience at all.

Comment: You don't need to use a sledgehammer to hammer a tack--use a formula field.  I could help you with the formula, but I don't understand the logic as you've written it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//{@Commission}
If {table.PrincipalAmount} < 25000.99 Then
  125
Else If {table.PrincipalAmount} < 50000.99 Then
  250
Else
  0
```

You could also use a CASE statement:

```
// {@Commission}
Select {table.PrincipalAmount}
Case < 25000.99: 125
Case < 50000.99: 250
Default: 0
```